# How to get the name attribute in a bound function in react?

Tags: reactjs

```js
class ProfilesList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      profiles: [],
      filterConditions: [
        { gender: null },
        { age: { from: null, to: null } }, // Should be shown as age in years
        { height_cms: { from: null, to: null } }, // Should be shown as height in feet and inches (cms in brackets)
        {
          religion: [
            /* multi-select dropdown */
          ],
        },
      ],
    };

    this.onSideMenuChange = this.onSideMenuChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSideMenuChange(value, selectedOptions) {
    console.log("Side Menu changed", value, selectedOptions, this);
  }

  render() {
    const { profiles } = this.state;

    const optionsGender = [
      { value: "Male", label: "Male" },
      { value: "Female", label: "Female" },
      { value: "Trans-Gender", label: "Trans-Gender" },
    ];

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider width={250} className="site-layout-background">
          <Menu
            mode="inline"
            theme="dark"
            defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
            defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
            style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key="sidemenu_gender">
              <Cascader
                name="sidemenu_gender"
                options={optionsGender}
                onChange={this.onSideMenuChange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="sidemenu_age">
              <Cascader
                name="sidemenu_age_from"
                options={optionsGender}
                onChange={this.onSideMenuChange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="sidemenu_age">
              <Cascader
                name="sidemenu_age_to"
                options={optionsGender}
                onChange={this.onSideMenuChange}
              />
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I get the name of the Cascader (e.g. `sidemenu_gender`) in the onSideMenuChange function? Sorry, if this is a very basic question (I'm very new to reactjs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Cascader` (whatever it is) doesn't pass the name prop down, you need to pass that information yourself.

Since you're already using [`.bind`, you can use it for partial application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Syntax):

```
// in the constructor
this.onGenderSideMenuChange = this.onSideMenuChange.bind(this, 'gender');
this.onAgeFromSideMenuChange = this.onSideMenuChange.bind(this, 'age_from');
this.onAgeToSideMenuChange = this.onSideMenuChange.bind(this, 'age_to');

// notice added `menu` parameter:
onSideMenuChange(menu, value, selectedOptions) {
  console.log("Side Menu changed", menu, value, selectedOptions, this);
}

// in render:
<Cascader options={optionsGender} onChange={this.onGenderSideMenuChange} />
```

Comment: Ah, so there is no way to pass the name prop down?

Comment: It would depend on the `Cascader`'s implementation. You can also do the binding in-place (with a performance hit you probably don't need to worry about): `onChange={(...args) => this.onSideMenuChange('gender', ...args)}`